# Doctrine2 criteria expression between two times

Tags: datetime, doctrine-orm

i have an entity "Company" with an one to many association to its opening hours. The opening hours entity has two fields (start and end) of the type time. Now i want to write a company method "isCurrentlyOpen" which returns a boolean value, but i can't get it...

**Company**

```
class Company {
    /**
     * @var \Gastronome\Entity\OpeningHours[]
     * 
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Gastronome\Entity\OpeningHours", mappedBy="gastronome", fetch="EAGER")
     * @ORM\OrderBy({"weekday" = "ASC", "start" = "ASC"})
     */
    private $openingHours;

    public function getOpeningHours() {
        return $this->openingHours;
    }

    public function getTodaysOpeningHours() {
        $criteria = Criteria::create()
            ->where(Criteria::expr()->eq('weekday', (int) date('w')));

        return $this->getOpeningHours()->matching($criteria);
    }

    public function isCurrentlyOpen() {
        $criteria = Criteria::create()
            ->where(Criteria::expr()->gt('start', new \DateTime()));
            ->andWhere(Criteria::expr()->lt('end', new \DateTime()));

        return count($this->getTodaysOpeningHours()->matching($criteria)) > 0;
    }
}
```

**OpeningHours**

```
class OpeningHours {

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="time", nullable=false)
     */
    private $start;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="time", nullable=false)
     */
    private $end;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer", nullable=false)
     */
    private $weekday;

    /**
     * @var \Gastronome\Entity\Gastronome
     * 
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Gastronome\Entity\Gastronome", inversedBy="openingHours")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="gastronome_id", referencedColumnName="id", nullable=false)
     */
    private $gastronome;
}
```

Comment: check the database field value.  Your column type is time so data is stored only time without date, time and timezone information, so you can't compare with a fully datetime.

Comment: database field value is for example "20:00:00" and has the type "time". But how should i compare to this?

Comment: mmm... try comparing as string: format the datetime and take only the time part, something like : `->where(Criteria::expr()->gt('start', $now->format('H:i:s');));` hope this help

Comment: already tried, unfortunately no result...

Comment: DominikBarann Have you found a solution to achieve this? I have a similar scenario and did the same @Matteo suggest but no luck yet :(